# Django doesn't create any tables in Postgres database

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I have an app with an initial data fixture on Django 1.8. When I run `manage.py migrate`, I get the following output:

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: food, locations, messages, staticfiles, core
  Apply all migrations: auth, sessions, admin, contenttypes
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
/home/myuser/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py:229: RemovedInDjango19Warning: initial_data fixtures are deprecated. Use data migrations instead.
  RemovedInDjango19Warning

Installed 87 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

So it seems like the fixture was installed, but not really - when I log in to my postgres user and run `psql` and `\dt`, no tables are listed (I make sure to connect to the database first with `\c mydatabase`)! When trying to view the app in a browser, I get: `ProgrammingError at / relation "locations_openinghours" does not exist`. (Which just happens to be the first table that the app tries to access).

Comment: have you tried running ```python manage.py makemigrations``` before running ```python manage.py migrate``` ?

Comment: Yes, I did this before - and when I do it again, I get `No changes detected`. There are no folders called migrations anywhere in my project (none were created).

Comment: Can you add more info? Like show us code snippet of your model and maybe ```INSTALLED_APPS``` section of your settings?

Comment: Yes, I've done that now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, but it was a silly issue. First, when running `python manage.py makemigrations` for the first time, you should specify which app you're migrating for - so I used `python manage.py makemigrations myapp`. Secondly, the way I've set up my project, `manage.py` uses the dev settings by default, and this was writing to an SQLite database. I added the `--settings=core.settings.production` flag, and it worked.

Comment: the dev setting thing has caught me out before too :-)

Comment: where did you add settings=core.settings.production flag ? do i add a line settings=core.settings.production in manage.py

Comment: I changed DB names in settings.py , then did migrations, then restarted server and it worked. I had to create new data and then it showed up in my postgres DB

Answer (score 2):

You can try these steps to see if it resolves your problem:

1. delete all the migration files for your app, as well as the database records for the app migrations in the `django_migrations` table.
2. Run: `python manage.py makemigrations <appname>`
3. Run: `python manage.py migrate <appname>`

In addition to the above you can try adding to each of your model classes the meta class setting `managed = True` and `app_label = <name of your app>`

i.e.

`class Food(models.Model):
       class Meta:
           app_label = "food"
           managed = True`

The rest of your class as you had it. Of course add this Meta for all your models. Make sure the `app_label` is lower case like you have it in the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: This solution did not worked for me .. it actually creates default entry database but not the secondary entry which is in another section of databases also I have a database router could this be a reason? basically I am able to connect with the existing manually created database. But new postgresql database is not getting created with about migrations commands.